# Does my Giant Crocodile's grapple benefit from my Druid's expertise? (wild shape)

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, grapple, wild-shape, proficiency

Put another way, when is a grapple(MM) not a grapple(PHB)?

My wild shaped Circle of the Moon druid loves to be a giant crocodile.  Big and strong, he can *grapple* much bigger creatures than our barbarian can.  He is huge, so he can grapple Huge and larger creatures.

> ***Bite.*** *Melee Weapon Attack:* +8 to hit, reach 5 ft., one target.
>   *Hit:* 21 (3d10 + 5) piercing damage, and the target is grappled (escape DC
>   16). Until this grapple ends, the target is restrained, and the crocodile
>   can't bite another target. (MM, [Giant Crocodile](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/giant-crocodile))

So where does this DC of 16 come from to keep the grapple?
8 + (strength bonus~5+ +  (CR 5 proficiency bonus~3) = 16.
(It is of interest that the giant crocodile is not listed as having the Athletics ability the way that a giant does.)

#### Druid is not polymorphed; he is wild shaped.

The [Wild Shape](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/druid#WildShape) feature says:

> While you are transformed, the following rules apply:
>
> Your game statistics are replaced by the statistics of the beast, but
>   you retain your alignment, personality, and Intelligence, Wisdom, and
>   Charisma scores. You also retain all of your skill and saving throw
>   proficiencies, in addition to gaining those of the creature. If the
>   creature has the same proficiency as you and the bonus in its stat
>   block is higher than yours, use the creature’s bonus instead of yours.
>   If the creature has any legendary or lair actions, you can’t use them.
>   (PHB, Wild Shape).

My druid has *Athletics proficiency*(from outlander), and took a level in rogue to get *Athletics expertise*.  His proficiency bonus is 4, which doubles to 8 when grappling or shoving in druid form.

Should I double the proficiency for the giant crocodile and compute the DC as 19, rather than 16, since I retain my abilities and proficiencies?  (Double the +3, not the +4, in this case).
8+5+3+3 = 19

Or, is this a case of "that grapple isn't the same as the other grapple" even though the same term is being used?  The reason for my uncertainty is that a PHB grapple does not, by default, restrain a creature (that takes the grappler feat), while certain monsters restrain a creature when they grapple them. (Ropers, for example).

Comment: @Miniman i don't think this is a dupe, since I am not trying to use my athletic score, but double the proficiency to calculate the DC due to having expertise.  (Doubling proficiency bonus).  that is why this question is different.  A significant issue here is "is a grapple a grapple" or not?

Comment: it is the same question in that you are trying to replace a DC in a monsters attack. That is not doable via a class feature involving the Athletics skill as it is nowhere mentioned that the attack uses Athletics (the other question covers the same topic)

Comment: @DavidCoffron It occurs to me that the MM grapple is like a spell, or like a Monk's knock prone (using ki and a 'spell save' form ki based on wisdom), rather than PHB grapple, which is an Opposed Ability Check.  That seems to be where the confusion lies: it is the very same game term, but applied differently between MM and PHB *and* often that special grapple includes a restrained condition which a normal PHB grapple does not.